# projective submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, projective-space, submanifold

> Given the smooth manifold $M = RP^2 \times \Gamma$ where $RP^2$ is the real projective plane and $\Gamma$ the unitary cylinder, verify that
> $$Z := \left\{ \big((y_0: y_1: y_2), (x_1, x_2, x_3)\big) \in M :\space y^2_0 = y^2_1 + y^2_2, x_1 = {1\over2}\right\}$$
> is an embedded sub-manifold of M.

I'm a little bit confused because if there were no projective, I would have used the result that pre-image of regular value is a sub-manifold with a light heart, but in this case, I was thinking about using slice condition or similar. There exist a "smarter" way to proceed rather than calculations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand why you just don't use the regular value theorem, the projective plane is still a real manifold.

Comment: because than I have to define a map $F: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and verify for each chart of M the smoothness of $F$ and I was wondering for an alternative method @Levent

Comment: Working with subsets of projective space, Euler’s Theorem on homogeneous functions is your friend.